# Drag Emails From Outlook to Java (with JNA)

Tags: java, eclipse, outlook, swt, jna

I'm trying to transfer Emails from Outlook to an Eclipse RCP application via drag and drop. Using this [Code Snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet83.java) I found out that the following native types are transfered during the drag and drop operation from Outlook 2010 to Java:

[image]

I need the full message body, therefore the provided text during the drag and drop operation is not enough. I have tried to extend [ByteArrayTransfer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/dnd/ByteArrayTransfer.html) in order to convert the native objects into Java objects, which provides access to the email. Structures like [FileGroupDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are native C structs. I tried to read them out using JNA, but JNA fails to convert the C struct into an object of my Structure class.

I have two questions:

1. What's wrong with my JNA code?
2. Does someone know a better way to read out native drag and drop structures in java?

Code from extended ByteArrayTransfer class:

```
    public class FileGroupDescriptor extends Structure {
        public int cItems;
        public FileDescriptor[] fgd;

        public FileGroupDescriptor() {
            super();
        }

        public FileGroupDescriptor(Pointer pointer) {
            super(pointer);
        }
    }

    public Object nativeToJava(TransferData transferData) {
        if (transferData.type == 49478) {
            Native.setProtected(true);

            byte[] buffer = (byte[]) super.nativeToJava(transferData);

            Memory memory = new Memory(buffer.length);
            memory.write(0, buffer, 0, buffer.length - 1);

            Pointer p = memory.getPointer(0);
            FileGroupDescriptor groupDescriptor = new FileGroupDescriptor(p);

            System.out.println(groupDescriptor.cItems);
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: I currently work on a plugin for eclipse called eclipsemail. Interested?

Comment: Actually I don't need an email client. I just want to archive emails.

Comment: It can display emails. *nictate*

Comment: Can it also read out Windows OLE structures?

Comment: We're using something called OutlookDD.  I'm not sure where my teammate found it (I'm not sure it's free, we might be paying for it) that lets us drag messages into Java as MSG files, including all content.  The package is de.wim.outldd, but looking at the source files, there's no obvious copyright details to say where to get it...

Comment: The source code seems to be from this project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaoutlookdd/ Unfortunately it is licensed under GPL. Anyway nice comment!

Comment: @TobiasWillig well, no, the OLE-Features of SWT are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominally, this is how you need to initialize the JNA structure.

```
public class FileGroupDescriptor extends Structure {
    public int cItems;
    public FileDescriptor[] fgd;

    public FileGroupDescriptor(Pointer pointer) {
        super(pointer);
        this.cItems = pointer.readInt(0);
        this.fgd = new FileDescriptor[this.cItems];
        this.read();
    }
}
```

That should be sufficient to provide the information you're looking for in the `fgd` field.  You should also write the entire `byte[]` length into memory; not sure why you're omitting the last byte (this isn't a C string).

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I'm now implementing the whole thing in C++.